# How to use Laravel form model binding with array as name attribute?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I want to use form model binding in Laravel. The following (simplified) example works fine:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
    {{ Form::token() }}

    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
    {{ Form::text('email') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

However, I want to use arrays in the `name` attributes, as is pretty standard nowadays. In other words, have `user[email]` as the field name, so that I get all the form elements in one array in the backend.

Is this possible with model binding? When I use `{{ Form::text('user[email]') }}` the email does not get filled in. I tried adding `array('user'=>$user)` in the `Form::model` function in case it needed a nested value, but no luck.

Comment: `Form::open()` and `Form::model()` will automatically add token, when ended with `Form::close()`

Comment: For the problem, you will probably need to use pure HTML to get the input names with array notation handled correctly. You can also use `Form::macro()` to simplify the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form::model(array('user' => $user))` is the correct solution, BUT unfortunately the implementation of form model binding is pretty bad as it does not easily work on a nested, mixed set of arrays and objects. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5074

You could try `Form::model(array('user' => $user->toArray()))` or `Form::model((object) array('user' => $user))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this assuming that you would have a **single `$user`** and **`multiple $types`**

```
Form::macro('userTypes', function($user,$types)
{
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $concat = $user . "_" . $type;
        return '<input type="{$type}" name="{$concat}">';
    }
});
```

And customize the output with your form style, even adding more complexity to the function might be required.

And then simply calling it for example

```
$user = "johndoe";
$types = array("email","text");
Form::userTypes($user,$types);
```

That would result in

```
<input type="email" name="johndoe_email">
<input type="text" name="johndoe_phone">
```

If you want to do it in a single line and assuming that you would have a **single `$user`** and a **single`$type`** you could do something like

```
Form::macro('userType', function($user,$type)
{
        return '<input type="{$type}" name="{$user[$type]}">';
});
```

And with the call

```
$user = [ "mail" => "some_mail_value" ];
Form::userType($user,"mail");
```

Would result in

```
<input type="mail" name="some_mail_value">
```

Or perhaps you'd like something that would work with a **single $user key-value array** as :

```
Form::macro('userType', function($user)
{       
        $keys = array_keys($user);
        foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
            return '<input type="{$key}" name="{$value}">';
        }
});
```

And with the call

```
$user = ["mail" =>  "mail_value" , "text" => "text_value"];
Form::userType($user);
```

That would result in

```
<input type="mail" name="mail_value">
<input type="text" name="text_value">
```

And finally I didn't find a direct way to do it with default form model binding, as It requires the field name to be the same as the model attribute, but you could do a workaround as

```
Form::macro('customBind', function($user_model,$type)
{       
    return '<input type={$type} name="user[{$type}]" value="{$user_model->$type}">';
});
```

And then

```
$user = new User();
$user->email = "johndoe@gmail.com";

Form::customBind($user,"email");
```

Which would produce something like

```
<input type="email" name="user[email]" value="johndoe@gmail.com">
```

The takeaway point is that basically the solution to your problem is creating a Macro, I have provided some workarounds on this but you will need to refine this to your specific needs.

Comment: But then I have the exact same problem - single values in the name attribute and not arrays. Unless there is a simple way to parse all those into a single array in the controller?

Comment: It's just a matter of tweaking the function, I do not know if you are planning on having multiple user objects on the page, so I'll update the answer with one suggestion for a single user object.

Comment: No, it's only one user. What I mean is, when I submit your form I get two separate input variables, `johndoe_email` and `johndoe_phone`. What I want is for the name attribute to be like `user[email]` and `user[phone]` so that I just get `$user` as an array in the controller.