# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to update a record of my table category, but it shows me the error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token'

**Route**

```
Route::post('/categorias/edit/{id}', 'CategoryController@update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = request()->all();
    Categoria::where('id', '=', $id)->update($data);
    return redirect()->to('categorias');
}
```

**Model**

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categoria';
    protected $fillable = ['id','codigo','nombre','descripcion','estado'];
```

**Form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => url('categorias/add') , 'class'=>'form-horizontal' , 'id'  => 'formulario' , 'method' => 'POST')) }}

{{ csrf_field() }}
<input id="idcate" name="id" type="hidden" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
<input id="txtcodigo" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

<input id="txtnombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

<textarea class="form-control" id="txtdescripcion" name="descripcion"></textarea >

<select id="cboestado" name="estado" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">NO ACTIVO</option>
      <option value="1">ACTIVO</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

*The records are in a table and I use the same form to edit and to add a new record, only that by clicking the edit button, I change the action*

```
$('#formulario').attr('action', '{{ url("categorias/edit")}}'+ "/"+ $('#idcate').val());
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your error comes from

```
$data = request()->all();
//which includes '_token'
//coming from csrf_field()
```

Do instead

```
$data = request()->except(['_token']);
//same as $request->except('_token');
```

Comment: Doing the exception, would not jeopardize the security of the form? , Is this the right way?

Comment: Not at all. `_token` still exists, but won't be part of the `$data` array. Still present in the request.

Comment: It worked, thank you for clarifying that security question.

Answer (score 8):

Just change this at your controller

```
Categoria::find($id)->update($data)
```

---

Comment: This worked for me since I used `whereId($id)` instead of `find($id)`

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this question are wrong about the proper procedure, what you should do is filter the data received by the variable $request, to do so, create an array and capture the fields of interest.

This is the basics, I personally would include several other validations, I foresee many things when dealing with security, but it should be enough for you to update without major problems:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; use App\User;         
     /**
     * This is just a demo, modify it according to your needs, include Facades\Auth in the header of the controler to search for the logged in user (Auth::user ())
     *
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         $use = Auth::user()->name;
         $user = User::where([['id', $id], ['name', $use]]);
         $request->validate([
          'name'=>'required',
          'email'=>'required'
         ]);
         $array = array(
          'name' => $request->get('name'),
          'email' => $request->get('email')
         );
         $user->update($array);
         return redirect()->route('home')->with('success','Update successfully');

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with accepted answer.

From my point of view it is better to use form model binding with array as name attribute (see [How to use Laravel form model binding with array as name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117152/how-to-use-laravel-form-model-binding-with-array-as-name-attribute)).

```
{{ Form::model(['user' => $user], array('class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
    {{ Form::label('user[email]', 'Email Address') }}
    {{ Form::text('user[email]') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In the controller you can access user data with the following code without bothering about other data transmitted on submit (eg. _method, _token, submit, ...):

```
$request->input('user');
```

If you want to use this approach, then you also have to update validation code.

Form model binding in Rails (the other framework I work with) has a far better implementation, the presented approach is the default.