# How solve error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function edit($id){
    $guests=Guest::with('programs', 'specialties')->find($id);
    return view('editform',compact('guests'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $guestupdate = Guest::find($id);
    $guestupdate->programs()->update($request->all());
    $guestupdate->specialties()->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/home/show'.$id)->with('alert', 'You have successfully updated');
}

class Guest extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'guest_id';
protected $table = 'guests';
protected $fillable = 
['guest_fname','guest_lname','profession','mobile','work_phone',
        'current_job','previous_job','work_address','DOB','DD','program_name','specialty_name'];

public function programs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Program::class, 'guest_show', 'guest_id', 'program_id')
        ->withPivot('subject', 'show_date');
}

public function specialties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specialization::class, 'guest_speciality', 'guest_id', 'speciality_id');
}

class Program extends Model
{
protected $table = 'programs';
protected $primaryKey = 'program_id';
protected $fillable = ['program_name','subject','show_date'];

public function guests()
{
    return $this- 
 >belongsToMany(Guest::class,'guest_show','program_id','guest_id')
        ->withPivot('subject', 'show_date');
}

}

class Specialization extends Model
{
protected $table = 'specialties';
protected $primaryKey = 'specialty_id';
protected $fillable = ['specialty_name'];
public function guests()
{
    return $this- 
>belongsToMany(Guest::class,'guest_speciality','speciality_id','guest_id');
}
```

This is my code of controller and model to edit data(just show by guest_id) then I would to update request all field from many to many relationship.
The edit URL true but when I click button to update data appear this problem column not found:1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update what's solve?

Comment: Can you add the query that you get back in your error message?

Comment: hdifen this query
update `programs` inner join `guest_show` on `programs`.`program_id` = `guest_show`.`program_id` set `_token` = LiQTnFrnk8Vb96XS7ovyYmmBJJjpweiI71fV7R24, `guest_fname` = محمد, `guest_lname` = فهمي, `profession` = فاحص جودة, `mobile` = 796548234, `work_phone` = 69832511, `current_job` = شركة مكامن, `previous_job` = شركة مكامن, `work_address` = عمان, `DOB` = 1988-11-03, `DD` = , `program_name` = نبض البلد, `specialty_name` = هندسة بترول, `subject` = جودة أنابيب النفط, `show_date` = 2018-10-30, `updated_at` = 2019-02-03 06:55:26 where `guest_show`.`guest_id` = 3)

Comment: @AlaaSalah check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870607/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-token-in-field-list-laravel). I think your error comes from `$request->all()` which includes `_token` coming from `csrf_field()`

So try changing `$request->all()` to `$request->except(['_token'])`; in your update function. Your new update function should look like below

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $guestupdate = Guest::find($id);
    $guestupdate->programs()->update($request->except(['_token']));
    $guestupdate->specialties()->update($request->except(['_token']));
    return redirect('/home/show'.$id)->with('alert', 'You have successfully updated');
}
```

For more study Laravel [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests)

Another issue might be the syntax in `->withPivot`, withPivot accepts array so change your code to below:

```
public function programs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Program::class, 'guest_show', 'guest_id', 'program_id')
        ->withPivot(['subject', 'show_date']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Iftikhar uddin ...I will do function in model then call it in controller...when run I share my answer.

Comment: Try the answer and let me know what's the output! If there is any error share it so that I can debug it!